# Javascript: Get click target of arbitrary element within div tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, the situation is the following.
I have a div element which serves as a container for all kind of other elements (especially `<a hre0="..."><img ...></img></a>` and `<iFrame>` tags):

```
<div id="myDiv">
```

So basically, what i wanna do is to get the click target (if applicable) for all kind of elements within this div tag, under the assumption that there is always only one click with target specified.

Speaking UI wise: I want to see the target link that the user sees when he hovers with the cursor over the element.

Is there a generic approach to achieve this?

Comment: This won't be possible e.g to catch click event target for cross origin iframe (if not specifically handled by this iframed page). Otherwise, just check for `$(event.target).closest('[href]').prop('href')`

Comment: not sure if understood a question , but maybe you need something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/kshqtv8j/2/

Comment: or vanilla.js : https://jsfiddle.net/2years50/1/

Comment: thanks! your solutions work fine if the target is not a cross origin iFrame. Is there a way to do so for cross origin iFrames as well? Maybe it´s possible to somehow access this url which is displayed at the bottom of the browser window when hovering over the div tag?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is find all the child elements of your wrapper div, then loop through them getting the 'href' property. Something like:

```
var children = document.getElementById('myDiv').children;

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var childElement = children[i];
  var destination = childElement.href;

// do whatever you want with destination here. You can also get the associated IDs etc.

}
```

Untested but should work.

Comment: thanks, it works for img tags, but for iFrame tags, delivered from another domain it doesn´t work. any other suggestions?